# Ask - Pass the props in react-native-scrollable-tab-view

Tags: javascript, tabs, react-native

So I'm working with React Native,

This is my Main Menu Codes. From here, everytime user click the button SOURS, I want to navigate to Sours page and pass the props amount: '50'. (From here everythings work as I expected):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text, 
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet, 
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Title, Button, Icon, Content, Thumbnail } from 'native-base';


module.exports = React.createClass({ 
  render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.background}>
            <Container> 
              <Content>
                <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}> 
                    <View style={styles.center}>
                      <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={() => {this.props.navigator.push({name: 'Sours', amount: '50'})}}
                        style={styles.buttonMain_}
                        underlayColor="#c5e29e" > 
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                      <Text style={styles.BtnMainText_}>SOURS</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>  
              </Content>
          </Container>
          </View>
        );
    }
})
```

This is my SOURS - Codes. In this section I'm using **react-native-scrollable-tab-view** Component, I tried to log **{this.props.amount}** and it gives me result **50**. (From here everythings work as I expected).
Then I tried to pass the **{this.props.amount}** to TabOne page in **'./sours_comp/sours'**

```
import React, { Component } from 'React';
import {
  Image,
  View, 
  StyleSheet, 
} from 'react-native';  
import Swiper from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view'

import TabOne from './sours_comp/sours'
import TabTwo from './sours_comp/history'

module.exports = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.amount);
  },

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Container>
          <Header>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigator.pop()}>
              <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
            </Button>
            <Title>Sours</Title>
          </Header>

          <Content>
            <Swiper>
              <TabOne tabLabel='Sours' >
                <TabOne amount={this.props.amount} />  // I tried to pass the amount props
              </TabOne>
              <TabTwo tabLabel='History' />
            </Swiper>
          </Content>
        </Container>
      </View>
    )
  }
})
```

In this TabOne code section, I tried to log **{this.props.amount}** and it gives me result **undefined**.

```
This is my TabOne - Codes. 
import React, { Component } from 'React';
import { 
  View,
  Text,  
  Alert
} from 'react-native'; 

module.exports = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.amount);
  },

  render(){ 
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Hallo {this.props.amount}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
})
```

Can you guys help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** - I realise that I made mistake in this lines (SOURS.js code):

```
<TabOne tabLabel='Sours' >
 <TabOne amount={this.props.amount} />  // I tried to pass the amount props
</TabOne>
```

This is how I fix this issue:

```
<TabOne tabLabel='Top Up' 
 navigator={this.props.navigator} 
 topupAmount={this.props.amount} > 
</TabOne>
```